# Why does Minecraft show this crash report about 'BlockEntity' when I try to log into certain servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Why does Minecraft say this:

> Server forgot to send required information to construct BlockEntity

It says this when I log into certain servers in 1.10, like Mineplex or Cubecraft.

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact issue today with 1.10.1

Try setting your version back to 1.10, I have had no issues with that.

If you don't know how to change your minecraft version, look here:
http://gamingedus.blog.ryerson.ca/educator-minecraft-resources/minecraft-how-tos/changing-your-minecraft-game-version/

Answer (score 4):

Setting the version back, anything besides 1.10.1 that the server still supports, seems to work for me. I had the same issue with Wynncraft

Answer (score 4):

Based on this [thread in the Minecraft Forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/2697615-1-10-1-problems), several people are seeing this with v 1.10.1.

One of the [Minecraft devs is asking people to report this error](https://twitter.com/SeargeDP/status/745602435612282880), and even mentions that [they plan to release 1.10.2 later today](https://twitter.com/SeargeDP/status/745588547088965633) with a fix:

> I've been told that we'll have 1.10.2 later today as well, because there is a crash happening in 1.10.1 that we didn't get in testing.

In the interim, flip back to an earlier version and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Set your version to 1.10.2.

That was a problem of forgotting to test a part of the Minecraft code on the dev side.

Bug Report Link: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-103978?jql=text%20~%20%22Server%20forgot%20to%20send%20required%20information%20to%20construct%20BlockEntity%22